# Listen to global variable change in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, .net-4.6.1

I have a global variable indicating if my app is in read-only mode

```
public static class Global
{
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
    private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private static bool _isReadOnly = false;
    public static bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _isReadOnly; }
        set
        {
            _isReadOnly = value;
            OnStaticPropertyChanged("IsReadOnly");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to listen to that in all my GUIs to turn off editing. For instance I have a DataGrid

```
<UserControl xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models" >
   <DataGrid IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=(models:Global.IsReadOnly)}"  />
</UserControl>
```

How can I listen to the global variable instead of a local one in my ViewModel? Currently I get the error message

> The name Global does not exist in the namespace Models.

But it does! And I already tried to recompile and restart VS.

Comment: That does not work for my already opened and initialized GUIs. They don't seem to reload the property.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with the StaticPropertyChanged approach? Are you using a WPF version prior to 4.5? Please share your code.

Comment: Are you sure that `Global` is actually a member of the `MyApp.Models` namespace?

Comment: @Clemens: 100% sure: `namespace MyApp.Models { public static class Global {} }`

Comment: Just to make that sure, you get the error message at runtime, or is it just the XAML designer complaining?

Comment: It is both. It crashes at runtime.

Comment: I've pasted your code into a new WPF project, and it just works. No idea what's going wrong on your side.

Comment: @Clemens: Found it. The namespace was right, but this class was in another assembly. Changing it to `xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models;assembly=MyAppInterfaces"` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a static property, you could use a singleton implementation. Than you have an instance and may implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Global : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Global() { }
    public Global Instance { get; } = new Global();

    private bool _isReadOnly;
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get => _isReadOnly;
        set
        {
            if (_isReadOnly != value)
            {
                _isReadOnly = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsReadOnly)));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Global.Instance}, Path=IsReadOnly}" />
```

---

As mentioned by Clemens in a comment, since .Net 4.5 there is a static PropertyChanged event that also works with static properties:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Since WPF 4.5 this is no longer necessary, because you can declare a `StaticPropertyChanged` event, which is consumed by WPF Bindings.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that one :)